# Use application properties file to pick the table name in a native query?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

I am using a native query in my Spring Boot application, and I want to be able to pick the table name from my properties file. I attempted using spel expressions and it does use the table name specified in the @Entity annotation...however I want to use something like `@Value(${table.name}` to inject the string "bookshelf" into the Entity annotation if that makes sense.

I have also attempted a different approach using a physical naming strategy from hibernate however it does not seem to replace the table name.

**entity class**:

```java
   @Entity(name = "bookshelf")
   public class Object{
   
   private String color;
   private String shape;
}
```

**Repository:**

```java
@Repository
public interface ObjectRepository extends CrudRepository<Object,Long>{

@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select color from #{#entityName} where shape =: shape)
public List<Object> findObjectsByShape(@Param("shape") String shape);
```

**application.yml**

```
table:
  name: bookshelf
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not good practise to dynamically pass table name from security perspective.It is not possible in `Hibernate` however you may use `Eclipse-Link` implementation if that is still required,

```
String tableName = "tablename";
String query = "SELECT * FROM " +tablename +"WHERE salary > 10000";
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't do this with annotations.

What you can do:

Inject an EntityManager with for example:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;
```

on the em you can call

```
em.createNativeQuery("your native query")
```

where can use any Value which you can access in your class.

BUT: please be aware this somehow already could be first step to open a sql injection attack on your application. if there is another way of achieving your goal than dynamically build queries, please go the other way.